# Insert Into table Exec SP with bad performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, insert, exec, query-performance

I am working on a datawarehouse. One of our staging tables that is refreshed every night has about 10 million rows. We are using a custom built ETL tool that I can't make too many changes to. The tool loads this staging table like this:

```
truncate stage_table;
insert into stage_table with (tablockx) (column1, column2, etc...)
exec load_stage_table @batch_id = @batch_input
```

The contents of `load_stage_table` has some setup and a select statement. I can't share the exact code, but here is a basic example.

```
create table load_stage_table
(
     @batch_id varchar(max) = null
)
as 

-- <update batch_id in batch_table>

-- collect data

select
    column1 = table1.column1,
    column2 = table2.column2,
    ...
from table1
join table2
    on table2.id = table1.table2_id
-- many more similar joins
```

The problem is that when I run the stored procedure as its meant to be run with our ETL tool, the run time is almost 30 minutes. However if I modify the stored procedure to have the insert statement on the inside, then it only takes 1 minute.

```
    create table load_stage_table
(
     @batch_id varchar(max) = null
)
as 

-- <update batch_id in batch_table>

-- collect data
insert into stage_table with (tablockx) (column1, column2, etc...)
select
    column1 = table1.column1,
    column2 = table2.column2,
    ...
from table1
join table2
    on table2.id = table1.table2_id
-- many more similar joins
```

After running this a few times both ways and examining the execution plans, it seems that parallelism is not used when the insert is outside the stored procedure.

Does loading the table from the return, outside of the stored procedure, prevent parallelism? Or is this an indicator that the select statement needs some query tuning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`INSERT...EXEC` *might* prohibit parallelism, but I highly doubt that is the main issue here. The problem is that `INSERT...EXEC` works differently than `INSERT...SELECT`. When inserting the results of a query (i.e. a `SELECT` statement or `OUTPUT` clause) into a table, the results are streamed into the table. If you are watching the `row_count` and `used_page_count` from `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`, you will seem them increase immediately as the `INSERT...SELECT` starts.

But, when inserting the results of an `EXEC` (typically a Stored Procedure but could be Dynamic SQL), the sub-process / Stored Procedure needs to fully complete before anything is inserted into the table (yes, I just tested this). If you are watching the `row_count` and `used_page_count` from `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`, you will seem them stay at `0` (or whatever they started at) for a *looooong* time after the `INSERT...EXEC` starts. This is not a recipe for success when the Stored Procedure returns millions of rows as those results need to be stored somewhere prior to them being inserted into the table.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for insert-exec it to create a temp table in the caller and have the callee populate it if it exists.  If it doesn't exist the callee can still populate its own local copy and return as a select to serve vintage callers and for easier debugging.  This also works for dynamic sql!

Callee USP:

```
  declare
      @returnAsSelect bit = 0;

  if (object_id('tempdb..#MyUspNameResult', 'u') is null)
  begin
       create table #MyUspNameResult (
          ObjectId bigint not null
       );        
       set @returnAsSelect = 1; 
  end
    
  insert into #MyUspNameResult
  select ObjectId from ...;

  if (@returnAsSelect = 1)
     select ObjectId from #MyUspNameResult;
```

Note that if a vintage caller continues to do an insert-exec they will see slightly worse performance because of the needless temp table.  But is is only "slightly" because the insert-exec effect is still usually the dominant by >3x.